# android outOfMemoryError while displaying dialog with all apps

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, drawable

I get this while displaying an dialog showing all installed apps

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:712)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1148):        at android.content.pm.ResolveInfo.loadIcon(ResolveInfo.java:226)
```

in the dialog i am iterating over a `List` of `ResolveInfo` and i load the app icon through:

```
Drawable app_icon = allappslist.get(i).loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));
```

but this sometimes produces that error above...

Comment: Use MAT to figure out where your memory is going.

Comment: hmm i looked it up and all the drawables are stored in the vm heap, and if there is a certain amount of apps, it is too much allocated memory, so what can i do? why do other apps (like apex launcher, ...) dont get this ount of memory error independent of the amount of installed apps?

Comment: "so what can i do?" -- fix the memory problems elsewhere in your app. The app icons may be "the straw that broke the camel's back", but that is likely all they are. If MAT is showing you that those icons, alone, account for tens of MB of heap space, *then* you have an issue unique to those icons. Otherwise, your problems lie elsewhere in your app.

Comment: yes, all the 100+ app icons ale loaded into heap space,after the 20th or so it chrashes... do you know how i can get thwm out of the heap??

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue from Google Developer Console in `Crashes & ANRs` reports:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1048588 byte allocation with 250994 free bytes and 245KB until OOM`

Anyway, as my application also gets all installed apps, I've done a couple of things.

1- Used [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class to cache all bitmaps, you can use this class also I've found here on StackOverFlow's answers:

```
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

//This class to cache bitmap apps icon
public class Cache {

    private static Cache instance;
    private LruCache<Object, Object> lru;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    private Cache() {
        lru = new LruCache<>(5 * 1024 * 1024) //Max is 5MB;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public static Cache getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Cache();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    public LruCache<Object, Object> getLru() {
        return lru;
    }
}
```

---

2- Reduce the app icon dimensions using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`, which will reduce the size of it, [more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)).

---

A snippets of code to check the cache and get the bitmap:

```
Object appBitmap = Cache.getInstance().getLru().get(this.packageName);
if(appBitmap == null){
    Drawable drawableAppIcon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawableAppIcon).getBitmap();
    this.appIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 40,40,true);
    Cache.getInstance().getLru().put(this.packageName, this.appIcon);
} else{
    this.appIcon = (Bitmap)appBitmap;
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can go through this tutorial. It's really helpful.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: hmm but i dont understand how to prevent an ount of memory error if i load just some (100+) different app icons

Comment: Maybe a little help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130741/android-loadicon-generates-outofmemoryerror