# android loadIcon generates outOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-drawable

I just have a little `ListView` containing all installed apps and their icons
but if there are too much Apps installed i run into `outOfMemoryErrors` while doing

```
Drawable app_icon = applicationInfoList.get(i).loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));
```

that for every `ListEntry` (this line is written in my `ListAdapter`)

no problem so far, i understand why i ran into this error (too much icons loaded, too few vm heap)
but i had a look at the source code of androids **`ManageApplications`** Activity in the settings
and i never run in any of those **oom errors** while using the settings `ManageApps`
but the weird thing is that they do it **EXACTLY THE SAME WAY**

as you can see in their source here:
[the `ManageApplications` activity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java)
[where the `Drawable icon` gets loaded](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/settings/applications/ApplicationsState.java#ApplicationsState.ensureIcon%28com.android.settings.applications.ApplicationsState.AppEntry%29)
[where it is set in the list view](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/settings/applications/ManageApplications.java#ManageApplications.ApplicationsAdapter.getView%28int,android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup%29)

but i really dont understand why do i get a oom and they dont?

Comment: Urgent, Did you solved it?

Comment: i have created a `LruCache` now that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.
I'm now loading every image into a cache before using it.
If the cache gets full, the oldest element will be discarded,
so new ones can get cached.
additionally im resizing my images into smaller icons.
that did it.

Comment: Congratulations, could you please share your code? Is that similar to Google's BitmapFun Demo?

Comment: It's good you solved it, but if you have already decided to keep the question, at least share the solution.

Comment: @SagiLow So haven't I done that? Re-read my Answer please. I have told you everyrhing I have done: Avoiding the Problem

Comment: @Malte Shmitz What kind of cache ? is it disk cache ? just a 'list' ?
I think you wouldn't have mark this as an answer if it was someone else and not yourself

Comment: @SagiLow One shouldn't mark the perfect answer but the one which solves the problem best. And to answer your question: I have used the simple `LruCache` class from android and a scaling alogrithm which you can find everywhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Resize your icons into small images, you will be fine! (had this problem before, too)

Comment: but it isn't done in the ManageApplications Activity - so where is the difference between my code and their code?