# Android Async LoadIcon OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory-leaks

On some particular devices loadicon for the applications throws OutofMemoryError

```
private static class LoadIconTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, View> {
        @Override
        protected View doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                final PackageInfoData app = (PackageInfoData) params[0];
                final PackageManager pkgMgr = (PackageManager) params[1];
                final View viewToUpdate = (View) params[2];
                if (!app.icon_loaded) {
                    app.cached_icon = pkgMgr.getApplicationIcon(app.appinfo);
                    app.icon_loaded = true;
                }
                // Return the view to update at "onPostExecute"
                // Note that we cannot be sure that this view still references
                // "app"
                return viewToUpdate;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error loading icon", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

On MainActivity,

```
final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PackageInfoData>(this,R.layout.main_list,  R.id.itemtext, apps2) {

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if ( holder != null) holder = new ViewHolder();
           ...
  holder.icon.setImageDrawable(holder.app.cached_icon); 
  if (!holder.app.icon_loaded && info != null) {
     //this icon has not been loaded yet - load it on a
     // separated thread
     try {
    new LoadIconTask().execute(holder.app, getPackageManager(),convertView);
     } catch (RejectedExecutionException r) { }
    ...
   }
}
```

PackageInfoData class

```
public static final class PackageInfoData {
        ApplicationInfo appinfo;
        /** cached application icon */
        Drawable cached_icon;
        /** indicates if the icon has been loaded already */
        boolean icon_loaded;

}
```

I tried to reproduce this on my device, but with limited number of applications this doesn't happen. Any help ?

Comment: Since you create a `ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();` new holder every time, `icon_loaded` will always be false. Thus it is starting async task for each position resulting in `OOM`. Can you fix your logic based on this observation?

Comment: No, I create ViewHolder only if it's not null

Comment: Updated the code to reflect that. sorry about it.

Comment: Its the same thing: you define a `ViewHolder holder;` then check if is null. (It will always be null) then you create it. Also it would help if you paste the whole `getView` code.. so all the bugs (if any more) can be spotted at once..

Comment: Maybe a little help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130741/android-loadicon-generates-outofmemoryerror